# Div doesn't contain nested elements

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome, sublimetext2

I have been having trouble with one of my divs for some reason, even though the nav tags are nested within it when I inspect element with firefox or in chrome the div seems to be completely on its own.

```
<div class="nav">  
  <nav class="social">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><img class="icon" src="assets/facebook.png" alt=""></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img class="icon" src="assets/google.png" alt=""></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img class="icon" src="assets/linkedin.png" alt=""></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img class="icon" src="assets/twitter.png" alt=""></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img class="icon" src="assets/wordpress.png" alt=""></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- @include _nav -->
</div>
```

Maybe this is something to do with the css styling for it so here is the css too. I have a feeling it might be something to do with hammer for mac but it seems to work in other respects.

```
.head {
padding-top: 25px;
overflow: hidden;
padding-bottom: 10px;
// background-color: yellow;
}

h1 {
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
color:white;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 35px;
text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc, 
           0 2px 0 #c9c9c9,
           0 3px 0 #bbb,
           0 4px 0 #b9b9b9,
           0 5px 0 #aaa,
           0 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
           0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
           0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3),
           0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
           0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25),
           0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
           0 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
padding-bottom: 10px
}

.banner {
height: 200px;
background-color: red;
float: left;
margin: 0px;

}

.callout {
height: 200px;
background-color: green;
float: right;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-right: 0px;
}

.nav {
padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.headnav {
padding-top: 10px;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
}

nav li {
display: inline;
padding-right: 15px;
}

nav li:last-child {
padding-right: 0px;
}

nav li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
clear: both;
font-size: 20px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
}

nav li a:hover {
color: gray;
}

.icon {
width: 45px;
height: auto;
}

.social {
float: right;
overflow: hidden;
}

.social li {
display: inline;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I loaded your HTML into Chrome and the nesting looks correct in the Developer Tools. CSS can't change the DOM.

Comment: Ok so that obviously means its something else how do I add an image to my comment? I took a screen shot. Could it be something to do with using the 960 grid framework?

Comment: You may not have enough reputation to add images to your questions yet. It's quite possible that the grid framework is moving things around in the DOM -- what happens if you remove the grid classes and check?

Comment: So if I remove the links between the 960 stylesheet and the reset stylesheet nothing changes. The div still seems to be "in the background" is the best way to describe it. So it probably isn't either of them. So I don't quite understand what's going on.

Comment: are you including any html fragments via @include ? the html in that fragment could be causing the issue

Comment: You could get "View Source' and paste the html in a jsfiddle just to see your html

Comment: The is a nav element include. Would you suggest inserting the div in a build file after compiling or try and do things another way?

Comment: No. the way you have done it is just fine. Just double-check if an unclosed html tag somewhere else in the page is causing problem. Do you have permissions to put up a link here ?

Comment: It's just a website I am practicing on as I am just learning. The hammer publishing link is: hammr.co/347406/3

Comment: The link doesn't open up for me. Until that happens, I can only think of what would be the cause of your problem.

Comment: It works when I type it into Chrome on my iPad maybe it need the www. in front. I think this happened when I tried to show my brother.

Comment: All right...lets try this once again. Is the problem when you inspect it and see it in the elements panel or you just hover over the element in the elements panel ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As both your nav elements (`social`/`headnav`) contained within the div element (confusingly named "nav") are floated to the right and the left these are removed from the normal document flow (see [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) for more), and thus the div won't appear to "wrap around" or contain the elements when inspected in developer tools.

These elements are however still children of the div on the Document Object Model (DOM).

Normally an element that only contains floated children would have a height of 1px but in this case it is 10px due to the padding you have applied. This behaviour can cause a problem in terms of defining layout, for example margin below the parent, or styling like background pattern, colour or borders.

It is however entirely normal behaviour and not something you have done wrong.

There are several solutions to clearing floats so that the parent element area is affected by the floated children.

1. Adding another element after the floated elements with `style="clear: both";`

   `<br style="clear: both;" />`
2. Adding the style `overflow: hidden` to the parent container.
3. Using one of the clearfix methods listed on [CSS tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

Comment: Thanks very much for that pwdst. I'm just learning and trying to teach myself so sometimes come along little things like this that bug me and I like to know the answer, and I do now!